# Programs using electron give black screen

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

My laptop is showing black screens when I run programs like Atom or Discord. The programs load correctly and shows briefly when you resize it. You can see this effect with the minecraft launcher in the gif below:

[image: Example gif]

I've tried to reinstall the Nvidia control panel and drivers and install the newest updates but it's not solved.

I am running windows 10 Creators Update and have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 950m

I've looked online and found this https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4380 I know Discord and Atom are built on Electron I don't know if Minecraft uses Electron. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: It doesn't. You're likely having issues with "regular" 3D displays/OpenGL. What steps did you take to reinstall the Nvidia driver? Are you running Minecraft using the "High Performance" (GTX 950m) card or, assuming Optimus is available, the IntelHD?

Comment: I removed all the nvidia drivers which I could delete as soon as I restarted my pc they just reinstalled themselfs and when I run them on  the intelhd they work just fine

Comment: Did you try to manually get and install them from the official [Nvidia](http://nvidia.com/) website? Did you run the uninstall routine or did you manually remove the files?

Comment: I uninstalled from the offical routine and downloaded the new ones from the nvidia website

Comment: I tried to use DDU to uninstall all drivers. Still hasn't been fixed

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: Run your electron based apps (Atom, Postman, Visual Studio Code, ...) on Windows 10 in compatibility mode for Windows 8. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running on Administrator mode fixed the issue for me on windows.